# Is the Intel 7260 (rev c3) and Linux 4.6 kernel incompatible? No wifi!

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, drivers, kernel, iwlwifi

I am BRAND NEW to Linux, having just done a dual boot install of Ubuntu desktop 16.04 alongside Windows 10 in a new hp omen laptop. I have tried for the last several days so many different workarounds suggested in this forum to find a solution as to why the new system cannot find any wifi networks?? I am able to use a wired connection- but I need wireless. I'm guessing that my Intel card will only work on a earlier kernel, or that my particular card has no update available yet. I would be deeply appreciative for any suggestions that lead to a solution. 
Thank you to anyone who is willing to help!!!

Comment: It is not incompatible at all. Please provide the diagnostic wireless_script as described here. http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180

Comment: You could look in /var/log/syslog* and grep for firmware (sudo grep -i firmware /var/log/syslog*) and note if you have any firmware load failures, not followed by another successful firmware file load. If you find that, you could install `linux-firmware` using Synaptic, and that might fix your wireless (after a reboot). Keep us posted. Cheers, Al

Comment: I believe `linux-firmware` is installed by default in 16.04, @heynnema

Comment: thank you @chili555 - im not clear as to what you want me to provide?

Comment: thank you @chili555.  I feel stupid as i dont really understand what you want me to provide.  However, after I went to the link you provided, i pasted everything from "i would want everything in this script" into myu terminal and hit enter. this is what i got:

Comment: oops- @chili555 i do not know how to display the contents displayed in my terminal... i tried to paste them here, but it was like 1765 characters.

Comment: @chili555 can you let me know how to show the script here?

Comment: I have found some errors after running (sudo grep -i firmware /var/log/syslog*) that @heynnema suggested. when i open the software update window to search for additional drivers, it shows my NVIDIA binary driver version 361.42 from nvidia-361 as proprietary. i have that selected.  in Unknown:Unkown i have selected  "using processor microcode firmware for intel CPU's from intel-microcode (proprietary).... when I selected the later and authenticated, the entire software update window turned grey and locked up- offering only to wait or force quit.  Please forgive this sloppy reply.

Comment: Just to confirm... in terminal, type `dpkg -l intel-microcode` and see if it shows up as `ii` installed. Do the same for `dpkg -l linux-firmware` (those are lower case L's). Do you have Intel CPU's? If so, go back to `Software & Updates` and try to enable intel-microcode again and see what happens (this part is unrelated to your wireless problem, but it's something that should be working if you have Intel CPU's). Cheers, Al

Comment: thanks for reply @heynnema. I ran first command, this is what I got back   ~$ dpkg -1 intel-microcode
dpkg: error: unknown option -1

Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages [*];
Use 'apt' or 'aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;

Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through 'less' or 'more' !
grey4our@grey4our-HP-OMEN-Notebook:~$

Comment: @heynnema I wish I knew how to post the script in the right format here.  Im sorry. As I said, I am terribly new to this.  thanks again for your help

Comment: The -1 should have been a -l (lower case L). Cheers, Al

Comment: ahh- my bad! This is what your first command came back with     grey4our@grey4our-HP-OMEN-Notebook:~$ dpkg -l intel-microcode
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
rc  intel-microcod 3.20151106.1 amd64        Processor microcode firmware for 
g

Comment: i wish i could pm you with a phone number- i hope this forum would allow me to say that i would GLADLY pay you for a solution here.  Im very worried about having to abandon ship here.  If I end up having to uninstall this version of ubunto i am worried that it will take windows 10 with it. @heynnema, i have a lot to loose here.

Comment: Do you have Intel processors? Now do the same dpkg command for `linux-firmware`. ps: soon they'll ask us to take this lengthy conversation to a chat room, and there will be a link here to get there. Cheers, Al

Comment: The microcde firmware has nothing whatever to do with the Intel wireless. Please download the script I linked above and follow the instructions to make it executable and run it. It gathers all the needed data relating to wireless in one try. Paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: @heynnema Reputation 1 users are not yet allowed in chat absent a special exception.

Comment: I appreciate it guys- I will back in a little while. Unfortunately I had to leave the computer. Again, thank you for trying to help. I will return ASAP

Comment: @chili555, yes, you're correct. The `intel-microcode` has nothing to do with the wireless. I mentioned that above. `linux-firmware` might. We got a little sidetracked and I was trying to fix that for him too. Hopefully he'll execute your script and give you some clue as to his problem.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23142305/

Comment: @chili555.... I hope this will provide some useful information. please let me know if there is something i need to do or did wrong.  http://paste.ubuntu.com/23142305/

Comment: You need to paste the contents of this file: /home/grey4our/wireless-info.txt

Comment: Yes, indeed. Please paste /home/grey4our/wireless-info.txt  and give us the link.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45017/discussion-on-question-by-grey4our-is-the-intel-7260-rev-c3-and-linux-4-6-kern).

Comment: Ok- hey! I apologize for being away and such.

Comment: @chili555  can you help me understand how to find results for file: /home/grey4our/wireless-info.txt   I am challenged here, no doubt!  I pasted the file name in terminal and it came back with       /home/grey4our/wireless-info.txt
bash: /home/grey4our/wireless-info.txt: Permission denied

Comment: Go to your home directory. Do you see the text file wireless-info.txt? Right-click it and select 'Open with..' It ought to offer an application to open and read it such as Gedit. When you have it open, go to Edit > Select All. Copy it. Open http://paste.ubuntu.com and paste it there and give us the link. Until we see some diagnostics, we don't know what's wrong and therefor how to fix it!

Comment: @Grey4our, and just to finish a project that we started earlier... using Synaptic, you can install `intel-microcode`, reboot, and then enable that additional driver in Software & Updates. And you may have to reboot once more. In terminal, if you `sudo grep -i microcode /var/log/syslog` you can see it load. Cheers, Al

Comment: @chili555    here are the results.  Again, thank you for your patience       http://paste.ubuntu.com/23143620/

Comment: Can you please join us in chat at the link above?

Comment: @heynnema     Thank you again for the help!  after trying to install synaptic, I get this result in terminal    ~$ sudo apt install synaptic
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?        I dont know what is wrong? I remember mentioning earlier that the software update window is all grayed out offering me the only option to "wait" or "force quit".  I just right clicked and selected force quit and tried to install synaptic....

Comment: Please join us: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45017/discussion-on-question-by-grey4our-is-the-intel-7260-rev-c3-and-linux-4-6-kern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a condensation of a lengthy chat that solved the issue.

First, there was a partially installed but not configured package on your system. We remedied this with:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Once it ran correctly, the mis-configured package `shim-signed` was able to complete.

Second, You attmpted to install `intel-microcode` from 'Additional Drivers' but the process failed and was interrupted. Accordingly, after we verified that you indeed have Intel i7 processors, did:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall intel-microcode
```

After a reboot, we verified that the microcode was properly loaded.

In your pastes, there was evidence that the Broadcom driver `bcmwl-kernel-source` may have been incorrectly installed. We verified that it was not installed and therefore not conflicting.

Following these remedies, your wireless works!

We did notice, however, in your `dmesg` that the driver looks for the -17 firmware and doesn't find it, then looks for -16, finds and loads it. You might get an improvement in performance by installing the -17 firmware file. From the terminal:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.160_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

Reboot.

Comment: YES the wireless is working PERFECTLY!  I ran the install command you suggested and got this result    http://paste.ubuntu.com/23154490/   Is there anything else I need to do?  You have been a MAJOR HELP!!

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working. If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: http://askubuntu.com/tour